# Binding a TreeView to a nested dictionary<string, object> results in exceptions thrown on missing child

Tags: wpf, xaml, collections, binding, treeview

I have a Treeview bound to a list of nested Dictionary. Each dictionary consists of two keys : '**Name**' of type string, and '**Childs**' of type Dictionary with the same structure as the parent, and so on to an arbitrary level, which may be different for each item of the list.

The Xaml below shows the full tree (of 'Name keys), but in the VStudio output window i see a great deal of **exceptions** thrown on terminal items (leafs) which contains only the Name key (no 'Childs' as it should be, considering that the path ends there!). It's a normal behaviour, **maybe** related to the generic nature of the Framework binding engine? Should i ignore it? Thanks in advance.

**XAML:**

```
<TreeView x:Name="infoPanel" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding [Childs]}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Width="12" Height="14" Source="{StaticResource item_ico}" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                <Label Content="{Binding [Name]}" ToolTip="{Binding [Name]}" ToolTipService.Placement="Top"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: Show us the data model

Comment: The list is generated by a third party assembly. I don't know which model it use. Besides, if i had access to it i'd use model properties rather than raw data.